# hiding content when variable is not present

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am using php to publish news articles from my mysql database. The articles have images placed within their text. The images are stored as variables, each its own path. The problem is I don't always use the full complement of images for each article, and the way I've written it, a broken image displays.

In short, how can I keep broken images from showing up if say '$image_ii' or '$image_iii' does not exist for a specific ID.

The way I have it written out is as follows:

```
            <?php    
            include ('connect.php');               

            $friendly_url=$_GET['friendly_url'];
            $query = "SELECT * FROM entries WHERE friendly_url='$friendly_url'";
            $entries = mysql_query($query);


            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($entries, MYSQL_ASSOC))
            {
              $title = $row['title'];
              $author = $row['author'];
              $pub_date = $row['pub_date'];
              $content_i = $row['content_i'];
              $content_ii = $row['content_ii'];
              $content_iii = $row['content_iii'];
              $content_iv = $row['content_iv'];
              $image_i = $row['image_i'];
              $image_ii = $row['image_ii'];
              $image_iii = $row['image_iii'];
              $image_caption_i = $row['image_caption_i'];
              $image_caption_ii = $row['image_caption_ii'];
              $image_caption_iii = $row['image_caption_iii'];
              $pre_link = $row['pre_link'];
              $post_link = $row ['post-link'];
              $id = $row['id'];
              $friendly_url = $row['friendly_url'];
              $american_date = date("F d, Y", strtotime($pub_date));
              $friendly_content_i = nl2br($content_i);
              $friendly_content_ii = nl2br($content_ii);
              $friendly_content_iii = nl2br($content_iii);
              $friendly_content_iv = nl2br($content_iv);



              echo "
            <div id='post'>
                <div id='post-title'>$title</div>
                <div id='post-content'

                $friendly_content_i        

                <div id='media'> <img src='../$image_i' class='scale-image'>   </div>
                <div id='media-caption'> $image_caption_i </div>

                $friendly_content_ii  

                <div id='media'> <img src='../$image_ii' class='scale-image'>   </div>
                <div id='media-caption'> $image_caption_ii </div>

                $friendly_content_iii

                <div id='media'> <img src='../$image_iii' class='scale-image'>   </div>
                <div id='media-caption'> $image_caption_iii </div>

                $friendly_content_iv

            </div>

                <div id='post-footer'>  by $author <br> $american_date </div>


                </div>
            </div> ";

            } mysql_close($connection); ?>
```

Apologies if this is terrible, it's my first dynamic website.

Comment: Check if the image file exists using file_exists() function and display img if file exists

Comment: Stop using PHP's deprecated mysql_ API. I don't know about others but I, for one, have simply stopped answering questions that employ that code

Comment: Strawberry, point taken. Starting the conversion to mysqli!

Comment: Going down the `mysqli` road may be a bad investment if your time. PDO is a much more flexible, more fully featured database layer that can do everything `mysqli` can and then some. It's not MySQL specific, it has named placeholders, and above all else, a much more sensible API. If you're not too committed, it's worth switching. Even better, consider an ORM like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent).

Comment: It's also time to upgrade to PHP 7. It's been out for four years.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the following snippet

```
if (file_exists("../".$image_iii)) {
    echo "<img src='../$image_iii' class='scale-image'>";
} else {
    echo "<img src='../default-image' class='scale-image'>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sasikumarhx, since I am a beginner I really appreciate you writing out an example for me :-)

Answer (score 1):

You already told us the solution to your problem:

> if say '$image_ii' or '$image_iii' does not exist for a specific ID.

Use `if file_exists()` to check that your image exists, and don't output it, if it doesn't.

Furthermore I see you're using [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) - This is **deprecated** and very unsafe. You should use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I appreciate your input, I will see if I can put this to use. I am a super beginner. I understand that mysql is depreciated and unsafe, this is mainly to get my feet wet using php for the first time. I expect I will either re-write this, or just do my next project in msqli. Correct me if I am wrong, but as I understand it, since only I am inputing into the database (through an htaccess pw-protected page), only I could be responsible for sql injection.

Comment: @JordanBice You are correct - If you are the only one with access to the site, you're the only one who can perform SQL injection, however you might as well learn to do it right from the beginning instead of doing it wrong, and then having to get used to doing it right. Good luck :)

Comment: That SQL injection rebuttal you're giving is akin to: "Since only I'm woking on the electrical system there's no reason to do things properly or safely." No. **Use prepared statements with placeholder values** unless you have no choice. Too many problems are created by writing lazy, half-baked code. Do this properly the first time and you will never waste time chasing down stupid mistakes like a missing apostrophe or dealing with complaints from users about not accepting certain kinds of input.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding a solution that worked using:

```
                 if (!empty($image_iii)) { echo "<img src='../$image_iii' class='scale-image'>"; }
                                    else { echo "";}
```

That said, clearly you kind folks are right about me needing to swap over to mysqli...found this website as a good resource for [migrating code to mysqli](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/9199/post/3-Smoothly-Migrate-your-PHP-Code-using-the-Old-MySQL-extension-to-MySQLi.html). Thanks to everyone who responded, everyones comments were helpful.

Comment: Instead of having double negation here, the `else` evaluates to *if not not empty image* or *if not not not image contains something*, just reverse the blocks and remove the negation.